# how to change the value of elements in a QVector of QMaps

Tags: c++, qt, qmap, qvector

I have created a QVector of QMap and pushed some qmaps into the qvector.

```
QVector<QMap<QString, QString>> * x;
QMap<QString, QString> tMap;
tMap.insert("name", "jim");
tMap.insert("lname", "helpert");
x->push_back(tMap);

tMap.insert("name", "dwight");
tMap.insert("lname", "schrute");
x->push_back(tMap);
```

after this, I wanna change some values of x like:

```
for(int i=0; i<x->length(); i++){
    if(x->value(i)["name"] == "target"){
        x->value(i)["name"] = "new value";
        break;
    }
}
```

But changing the values of qvector doesn't work.

Comment: First of all, one seldom need pointers to containers. And I assume that the pointers you have really point somewhere valid?

Comment: yes, values of x are correctly set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the [`QVector::value`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#value) function returns the value *by value*.

That means it returns a *copy* of the value, and you modify the copy only.

Use the normal [`[]` operator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#operator-5b-5d) instead to get a reference to the map:

```
if((*x)[i]["name"] == "target"){
    (*x)[i]["name"] = "new value";
    break;
}
```